# Delayed_job going into a busy loop when lodging second task

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I am running delayed_job for a few background services, all of which, until recently, run in isolation e.g. send an email, write a report etc.

I now have a need for one delayed_job, as its last step, to lodge another delayed_job.

1. delay.deploy() - when delayed_job runs this, it triggers a deploy action, the last step of which is to ...
2. delay.update_status() - when delayed_job runs this job, it will check the status of the deploy we started. If the deploy is still progressing, we call delay.update_status() again, if the deploy has stopped we write the final deploy status to a db record.

Step 1 works fine - after 5 seconds, delayed_job fires up the deploy, which starts the deployment, and then calls delay.update_status().

But here,
instead of update_status() starting up in 5 seconds, delayed_job goes into a busy loop, firing of a bunch of update_status calls, and looping really hard without pause.

I can see the logs filling up with all these calls, the server slows down, until the end-condition for update_status is reached (deploy has eventually succeeded or failed), and things get quiet again.

Am I using Delayed_Job::delay() incorrectly, am I missing a basic tenent of this use-case ?

Answer (score 0):

OK it turns out this is "expected behaviour" - if you are already in the code running for a delayed_job, and you call .delay() again, without specifying a delay, it will run immediately. You need to add the parameter run_at:

```
  delay(queue: :deploy, run_at: 10.seconds.from_now).check_status
```

See [the discussion in google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/delayed_job/rG6HIXHSFuc)